# curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl

I tried to use curl to POST a JSON object to ElasticSearch server but keep getting globbing error
This is my curl command:
`curl -X POST "localhost:9200/school/_doc/10?pretty" -H "Content-type:application/json" -d "{"firstName":"Bilbo","lastName":"Baggins"}"`

And the error I get from the server :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "json_e_o_f_exception",
      "reason" : "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])\"{\"; line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{\"; line: 1, column: 2]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax issue with your `curl` command, proper `curl` command of your request is

```
curl -v -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"firstName":"Bilbo","lastName":"Baggins"}' 'localhost:9200/school/_doc/10?pretty'
```

Best way to use the Elasticsearch using REST format and [rest client like postman](https://www.postman.com/) but still if you want to use the `curl`, you can use this [online curl builder](https://curlbuilder.com/) to avoid the syntax issues.